# How to create realistic stainless steel gloss in Blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, node-editor

I'm trying to create a tin can.
I need to know how to create a light gray metal look.
I have tried mixing a Diffuse and Glossy BSDF, but it isn't quite what I am looking for. I need some light falloff to help get that "extra touch", but I don't know how to do that.

Similar to this effect
[image]

Comment: This videos from BlenderGuru might help
https://youtu.be/m1PkSViBi-M
https://youtu.be/t4MTnpnahu0

Comment: If you want to get serious about metals - perhaps more serious than you want to - this [Blender Artists thread](https://blenderartists.org/t/update-v1-6-cycles-pbr-thin-film-interference-and-metals/672094) maybe of interest. Note the link at the top to a node-based implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the setup I used.[image]

To start I added a cylinder (Shift + A), the edit mode and using Ctrl+R to put 24 cuts into the cylinder. The Selecting alternating circles (Alt-Click) and then scaling them (S+Y+.989) then (S+X+.989) Then I used the [Bevelr addon](https://gumroad.com/l/bevelr) to first bevel the smaller circles and then the Larger ones to create a smooth ridged can shape. (Bevelr will automatically create the vertex groups and add the Modifiers.) And edge split will also help as soon as Smooth shading has been enabled. The material set up is quite simple so not much to explain on that. Just make sure you have the colours right and the lighting will always be key.
Here is the final render at 256 samples.[image]